ModuleNotFoundError when importing a class from another python file
I encountered a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1' error when I tried to run code1.py where I import a class 'car' from the module1.py file. This is the directory:
PYFILES
|- dir1
   |- __init__.py
   |- module1.py
|- dir2
   |- __init__.py
   |- code1.py


Code1.py:
from dir1.module1 import car

new_car = car()


module1.py:
class car:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Car is created!")

I tried using sys.path.append('.../.../PYFILES/dir1') and it worked, but it was really inconvenient. I tried creating __init__.py files everywhere and it didn't work. There must be something that I am missing. __init__.py files are empty btw.

Does it work if you move code1.py to be on the same level as dir1?

@FrasherGray Yes, but I want to figure out why does this happen when importing from different levels. I created this code just to demonstrate the problem that I had in my project directory.

Does this answer your question? Importing files from different folder

@FrasherGray No

Try changing your directory structure to look like this instead:
PYFILES
|- modules
   |- __init__.py
   |- dir1
      |- __init__.py
      |- module1.py
   |- dir2
      |- __init__.py
      |- code1.py

Then you should be able to do:
from modules.dir1.module1 import car

new_car = car()

I answered a similar post to this a couple of days ago:
Python issue with importing from submodule including scripts that also import from submodule?

I changed it and got an error too:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
